# Facebook Rss feed issue

Tags: facebook, proxy, rss, feed

I am accessing the Facebook rss feed with the url https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=XXXX for our company updates and some times the url works and sometimes getting below error while accessing the url. Is this the url I need to use for company updates? Pls help.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: With what are you accessing the feed? Is this your own program or some rss reader?

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that facebook doesn't provide updates as an RSS feed. Maybe I'm mistaken but they always seemed to steer developers to use the `facebook graph` (see the [Facebook Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)). There are a lot of example of scripts that can display a facebook timeline/wall on a website or post to facebook from a script/website, a quick google searchh for "facebook graph script" + the function you want should turn up a nice selection of results.